# How to access api.openrouteservice.org through Androids Volley package

Tags: android-studio, request, android-volley

I want to access data on the openrouteservice API - specifically the distance between two given coordinates on the globe - from my Android application.
I have made requests and gotten viable responses from another API that converts two given addresses into their latlong coordinates using the same style of code this request is trying to execute. It works fine, the coordinates arrive and i can further utilize them no problem.

My problem is that i seem to be accessing the API wrongly because if I Log the URL as seen below and copy it from the Debug window into my browser it sends the request, gets a response and shows it in the browser window.
But my application doesn't recieve a response from the API as the onResponse code bit is never executed and the "Fetch done" Log never appears in the actual Debug Log.
The following is my setup of code, which uses Volley to access HTTP Requests and which works fine for other APIs.

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Log.d("Run =>","Query 3");
        String targetKoordURL = null;
        String startKoordURL = null;
        try {
            startKoordURL = startK.getString("lon").concat(",").concat(startK.getString("lat"));
            targetKoordURL = targetK.getString("lon").concat(",").concat(targetK.getString("lat"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String URLfin = "https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car?api_key=5b3ce3597851110001cf624823e587e7a80c4c6ab02af6d394585213&start="+startKoordURL+"&end="+targetKoordURL;
        Log.d("Debug =>", URLfin);

        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URLfin, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                store = response;
                Log.d("Run =>", "Fetch done!");
                continueImp();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if(error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                    sideFetcherHTTPRequestStart replace = new sideFetcherHTTPRequestStart();
                    replace.execute();

                    Log.d("VOLLEY_ERROR", "Retrying on Kilometer request");
                }

                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Accept", "application/json,application/geo+json,application/gpx+xml,img/png; charset=utf-8");

                return params;
            }
        };

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I am new to Volley too, I guess you forget to add the request to `RequestQueue` `object.

Comment: Oh my god I am stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add the request to request queue, try to do as following:

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(/*params*/);

//add above request to queue
queue.add(req);
```

Comment: Have some online fame sir, your pinpoint knowledge of my lack of brain capacity is astounding and i bow to your scanning capabilities